# Passing events from client component to server component to handle it

Tags: next.js, event-handling

I'm currently struggling to understand the principle of passing down a function via props to a client component and then handling the response.

I'm on Next.js 13.5.2

My server component:

```
...
import FilterButtons from "./components/FilterButtons";
...
 <FilterButtons
        productTypes={productTypes}
        handleClick={filterProductsByType}
      ></FilterButtons>
...
```

My client component `FilterButtons`

```
type Props = {
  productTypes: ProductType[];
  handleClick: (event: any) => void;
};

export default function FilterButtons({ productTypes, handleClick }: Props) {
  return (
    <ButtonGroup className="ml-5">
      {productTypes.map((type: ProductType) => (
        <Button
          className={"transition ease-in hover:scale-105"}
          key={type.id}
          size="sm"
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          {type.name}
        </Button>
      ))}
    </ButtonGroup>
  );
}
```

I moved the `ButtonGroup` to a separate client component, as responding to event's inside of server components is not possible. I understand that.

But still the above code returns to me:

> Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server".
> <... productTypes={[...]} handleClick={function}>

The error message confuses me. Marking my Server component explicitly as `"use server";` does not change anything. Also, I cannot find any explanation why this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass data from client components to server components directly. because client components will be rendered on both the server and the client. That being said, if you try to pass data from a client component to a server component, there is no straight bridge between them when the client component is rendered on the browser. so you need an API to make the bridge between them.

however, there is an easier solution for that in Next 13, called [server actions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/server-actions). you can create functions that will be run on the server but can be called on the client. here is a sample of that:

```js
// src/my-actions/createPost.js
'use server'
 
export async function createPost() {
  // ...
}
```

```js
// src/components/my-form.js
'use client'
 
import { createPost } from './../my-actions/createPost.js'
 
export default function ClientComponent() {
  return (
    <form action={createPost}>
      <button type="submit">Create Post</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

please note that the server action is currently in beta (NextJS v13.5) and has some limitations. you can read the document for full information